# Getting IDA pro to understand that a "large" push can be two separate arguments?

Tags: ida

I am reversing a large 16-bit DOS application compiled with a borland compiler.
This often pushes one 32-bit value to the stack when a function takes two 16-bit arguments.

Is there any way I can get IDA to recognize this as two separate arguments?

Example:

Afunction is defined as:
`int __cdecl __far AFunction(int oneNumber, int anotherNumber);` (or with `__int16`, or `short` argument types)

This is an example of what IDA produces:

```
push    [bp+anotherNumber]   ; anotherNumber
call    irrelevant
push    large 40010h         ; oneNumber
call    AFunction
```

It treated the 32-bit value as one of the 16-bit arguments, and appplied a name and comment to a completely unrelated value (which is a real pain to get rid off at all call sites).

Is there any way I can get something like

```
push    [bp+var_4]
call    irrelevant
push    large 40010h         ; oneNumber: 04h, anotherNumber: 10h
call    AFunction
```

or

```
push    [bp+var_4]
call    irrelevant
push    large 0004h 0010h    ; oneNumber, anotherNumber
call    AFunction
```

or even

```
push    [bp+var_4]
call    irrelevant
push    04h       ; oneNumber
push    10h       ; anotherNumber
call    AFunction
```

?

Comment: No, IDA won't split that up for you as it's just disassembling and adding refs to things (as opposed to interpreting its semantics like a decompiler would do).

However, if you notice...those are really just comments and this is actually something you can script with IDAPython if you deem it as being necessary/critical to your reversing. If you're using a version of IDA with `idaapi.get_arg_addrs`, you would first grab the xrefs to "AFunction", use `get_arg_addrs` to get the parameter address, and then check the operand size. If it matches, you could then use `set_cmt` to add your comment.